# Automatically detecting code that will not run on earlier versions

Tags: compatibility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automated testing for compatibility with older Mathematica versions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2047/automated-testing-for-compatibility-with-older-mathematica-versions)

On my personal computer, I am running version 8.0.4, but on a compute cluster I would like to work with, they have stuck with version 6. With two major releases between the two, there is a lot of functionality in my version that is not present on the cluster. How might I detect which functionality will not be present on the prior versions? Obviously, the simplest method is to load the code into the prior version and determine which functions do not have a definition, but I would like to know before I run something on the older version if it will work, or not. Similarly, some functions have changed behavior or call signature between releases, so how might I detect this, also?

Comment: Also *very* strongly related: [automated testing for compatibility with older mathematica versions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2047/automated-testing-for-compatibility-with-older-mathematica-versions/2050#2050). The gist with the results from that post is [here](https://gist.github.com/1869086).

Comment: Actually, it looks to me to be an exact duplicate of that question, is it not?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Voted to close as a duplicate. Do you think my answer is sufficiently different from yours to warrant posting it to the other question?